# google organisation chart : Unable to display the organisation chart

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-visualization

Here is my database snap:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9vwi.png)

Here is my code:

```
<?php
 $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","organisation"); //db connection
 $query=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT name,below_whom FROM org"); //fetch data
 if($query){
 $data=[];
 while($org_data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
 $data []= [$org_data["name"],$org_data["below_whom"]]; //syntax of 
 associative array = $variable["value"]
 }
 #echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); echo '</pre>';
 }
 else {
 "Error".mysqli_error();
}
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'name');
data.addColumn('string', 'below_whom');
data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');
data.addRows(<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>);
var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')); 
chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
}
</script>
<div id="chart_div"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

I have been going through the documentation for quite sometime now and I am still clueless. I guess error is somewhere near addRows but I'm unable to trace it.

Comment: any errors in the browser's console? will you please share a sample of --> `json_encode($data);`

Comment: @WhiteHat Here is the sample of json_encode($data); :
[["Pratik",""],["Q","PFA"]]

Comment: @WhiteHat Console errors:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Row given with size different than 3 (the number of columns in the table).
    at gvjs_P.gvjs_.fZ (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:97)
    at gvjs_P.gvjs_.Op (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:98)
    at drawChart (testpi.php:16)

Comment: Oh god. I am embarrassed. I figured it out. Thank you anyway! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that there is no issue with your code, however the issue is in your data. Your queried data will be like this:

```
|name   |below_whom|
|-------|----------|
|Pratik |          |
|-------|----------|
|Q      |FTA       |
|-------|----------|
```

So you see, the "Q" has "FTA" as the boss, but google organization chart could not find "FTA". If you change "FTA" to "Pratik", you will see magic happens.